# Files encoding isse in chrome only

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I have different links which opens another page in a popup.The popup function is like this.

```
function popUp(URL) { 
eval("lesson = window.open(URL, 'lesson', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=600,left = 250,top = 50');");
}
```

When links are opened,its working fine in mozilla.When links are opened in chrome its giving me the following content
[image]

The filename  has spaces.I dont if this is happening because of this space or not because I am not able to rename or upload the files into that server

Comment: Why in heaven's name use `eval` for that?

Comment: The file name spaces are not the issue, if they were the content would not get loaded at all. But what are those invalid characters following each open tag bracket ("lower than character")?

Comment: Apart from that you should examine the mime type and enconding headers sent with the response. For that open your browsers development console and check the "network" tab. In there select the http request and study the "response headers".